# NgFor only supports binding to Iterables & Bootstrap-Select-Box is empty

Tags: angular, observable, iterable, bootstrap-select, ngfor

**SOLUTION:**

**We have solved 2 Problems here:**

> 1) Wrong assignment with **httpt.get**, we have got the error message:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object 
'[object Object]' of type 'object'. 
NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

> 2) Timing problem with **Bootstrap-Select-Box**; option-fields are empty

**1) WRONG ASSIGNMENT**

Following assignment is wrong:

```
this.agency = this.ws.get(serviceUrls.agency)
  .subscribe(
    (data:any) => this.agency = data,
    (err:any) => console.debug('AGENCY ERROR:',err),
    () => console.debug(this.agency)
  );
```

and gives the output:

[Object, Object, Object, Object,..]

[image]

what is not iterable via **ngFor** and should be corrected into:

```
this.ws.get(serviceUrls.agency)
  .subscribe(
    (data:any) => **this.agency = data**,  // <-- ONLY HERE
    (err:any) => console.debug('AGENCY ERROR:',err),
    () => console.debug(this.agency)
  );
```

**For the sake of completeness**, this is **ws.get-method**:

```
get(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map((data:any) => data.json());
  }
```

and this is the **agency**:

```
agency: any[];
```

**2) TIMING PROBLEM WITH BOOTSTRAP-SELECT & ANGULAR2**

That is the Bootstrap-Select-Box (a little bit - regarding CI - adapted version):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="localValues.agency"
        name="agency"
        id="agency"
        class="selectpicker select-search"
        data-selectpicker
        data-live-search="true"
        required="">
  <option
    *ngFor="let item of agency"
    [ngValue]="item.value">
    {{ item.label }}
  </option>
</select>
```

The activating of selectpicker happens in:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked () {
    //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  }
```

But **an importang thing was missing**; the select-box was rendered before the observables emit data. Therefore we have to check the existence of agency before and then render the box:

```
ngAfterViewChecked () {
    if (this.agency) {  // <-- IMPORTANT!
      //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    }
}
```

That's all! Maybe this information is useful for you too ;)

Comment: I think it is a timing problem, the select box is rendered, before observable delivers the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `Subscription` object by writing `this.agency = this.ws.get(serviceUrls.agency)` into variable `agency`. Don't do that. Leave it for you success function. Just remove `this.agency =`. Or! You can use [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) but remove your success callback.

You have problems with bootstrap-select because of [value] property. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843). So you should use [ngValue]. And one more thing, you are trying to the selectpicker when you actually have no data, but if you wrap the init into check for `this.agency` existance it will work.

Comment: I've tried both versions, I think bootstrap-select is not angular2 compatible :/ See my updated question,..

Comment: When do you init your bootstap select?

Comment: I think it is a timing problem, the select box is rendered, before observable delivers the data and it will not be updated ?

Comment: Does your select should receive data only once? Then move the initialization to success callback. Try it, but remove `this.agency = `

Comment: One more thing, try to use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`

Comment: already done, without success :/ I think, Bootstrap-select-box should get the information (however it is possible), that it should show the data, as far as it is delivered.

Comment: I know from angular1 ngValue would choose the right moment to update the data but in this case it did not work unfortunately,.. Furthermore maybe I need something like `[*ngFor]=` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121284/discussion-between-frione-and-vienna).

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what type `agency` is.
Seems like its `agency: any`.

If it would be `agency: any[]` it should work to iterate over it.

See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gV6FT0QiZwpybDxUzj1P?p=preview

import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <p *ngFor="let item of agency">{{item.value ? item.value : '--NOT THERE--'}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  agency: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'

    this.agency = [
       { anything: '' },
       { value: 'huhu', qwrtaj: null },
       { value: 'hehe', ufgjksak: null },
       { lksdl: null },
       { value: 'hoho', length: null },
      ];
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Nevermind, ts compiles to js. It has no type restriction. He set `agency` variable twice. First it is equal to `Subscription` class instance and then when observable gets value it will become an array.

Comment: You are right. `this.agency = this.ws...` is the problem.

Comment: I've tried both versions, I think bootstrap-select is not angular2 compatible :/ See my updated question,..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using

```
this.agency = this.ws.get(serviceUrls.agency)
      .subscribe(...)
```

I assume the definition of your `this.ws.get()` returns `Observable<Agency>` object. This is not what you want. This returned value will be an object of type `Observable<Agenc>` and not an array of Agencies, `Agency[]`.

Just calling:

```
this.ws.get(serviceUrls.agency)
    .subscribe(
        (data:any) => this.agency = data,
        (err:any) => console.debug('AGENCY ERROR:',err),
        () => console.debug(this.agency)
    );
```

should set the `this.agency` to contain an array of agencies.